# calculating seconds from a numbers/text column which represents the time in hours/minute/seconds

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

In Power Query i have a column which, for example looks like this

9h8m4s

this means 9 hours, 8 minute and 4 second. the challenge now is that i want to convert this value in the column to be the sum up of the hour, minute and second to be only second which actually equals to 32884 seconds.

and ideas about how to convert it in PowerQuery for Power Bi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WssywyDUpVoqNBQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom",
    each let
        h = Number.FromText(Text.BeforeDelimiter([Column1],"h")),
        m = Number.FromText(Text.BetweenDelimiters([Column1],"h","m")),
        s = Number.FromText(Text.BetweenDelimiters([Column1],"m","s"))
    in (h*60*60)+(m*60)+s)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, its the fastest solution ever for me in Stackoverflow :)

But i just discovered an issue, that not all the values in the column are hour/mins/seconds

Some doesn't contain hours or minutes just seconds like this: 

9h8m4s our example
8m4s
4s

any amendment for the code to work according to the other possibilities please?

Comment: sorry i updated my answer due to some other challenge but no worries i updated the your answer as solved.

Comment: The logic should be easy to update. Let me know if you're still having trouble or possibly ask a new question.

Comment: ya its simple, i could figure it out. thank you so much <3

Answer (score 1):

Split the column by the separators "h", "m" and "s" and combine them as a new column by multiplying minutes with 60 and hours with 3600.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromValue("9h8m4s"),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(
        Source, "Seconds", each 
        Number.FromText(Text.BeforeDelimiter([Value],"h")) * 3600 
        + Number.FromText(Text.BetweenDelimiters([Value], "h", "m")) * 60 
        + Number.FromText(Text.BetweenDelimiters([Value], "m", "s"))
    ),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Added Custom1",{{"Seconds", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply. i just noticed that some columns doesnt have the hour which is breaking the column logic :(

Comment: your code help me to comprehend the logic, thank you so much <3